# I just begining to learn codeigniter and I want to how can I change these php code to codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I just begining to learn codeigniter and I want to how can I change these php code to codeigniter

```
<? $sql="SELECT * FROM member";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($res); ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ลำดับ</td>
        <td>ชื่อ</td>
        <td>นามสกุล</td>
        <td>ระดับการใช้งาน</td>
        <td>การเข้าใช้งาน</td>
    </tr>
    <?
    for($a=1;$a<=$numrows;$a++){
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM log where user='$row[user_id]'";
    $res2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    $numrows2=mysql_num_rows($res2);
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$a?></td>
        <td><?=$row[user_name]?></td>
        <td><?=$row[user_surname]?></td>
        <td><?=$row[user_level]?></td>
        <td><?=$numrows2?></td>
    </tr>
    <? } ?>
</table>
```

how can I write model, controller, view

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need is to setup your appliction

setup data base in application/config/database.php

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'ci';//database name
```

Next autoload database in application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Now you need three things which are basics called Model View and Controller.
Let's do it step by step.

First you need to make a method in model class

Model name is Test_Model(application/models/test_model.php)

```
Class Test_Model Extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_members(){

        $query  =   "SELECT * FROM member";
        return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
    }
}
```

Next you need controller(application/controllers/test.php)

```
Class Test Extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function members(){
        /*  Load Model  */
        $this->load->model('test_model');
        /*  Call function to execute query  */
        $data['members']    =   $this->test_model->get_members();
        /*  Pass it to view */
        $this->load->view('members',$data);
    }
}
```

And the view(application/views/members.php)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ลำดับ</td>
        <td>ชื่อ</td>
        <td>นามสกุล</td>
        <td>ระดับการใช้งาน</td>
        <td>การเข้าใช้งาน</td>
    </tr>
    <?
    if(count($members) > 0){
        foreach($members as $row){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$a?></td>
            <td><?=$row['user_name']?></td>
            <td><?=$row['user_surname']?></td>
            <td><?=$row['user_level']?></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
        }
    }else{
        ?><td colspan='5'>No record found</td> <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

And now you can access this using this url

```
http://localhost/myapp/index.php/test/members
```

Where test is the name of your controller and members is the name of your controller method 
The info i provided is pretty basic. I recommend you first go through the [Documentation of 
Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/)

Comment: Thank you very much raheel shan.
But how can I get $numrows2 of each $user_id from another table(table "log") and show $numrows2 in the last column.